# Bootstrap navigation override

Tags: html, css, nav, bootstrap-5

I am currently trying to override my bootstrap navigation default styling, for some reason, this is not working. I have added the `!important` tag into my CSS as it seems like the most logical approach to take? But yet it's not working. I hope someone is able to assist me with this!

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="/Assets/logo.svg" class="me-5" alt="" height="80"> </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs- target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria- expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.navbar{
    background-color: #ffffff10 !important;  
    backdrop-filter: blur(12px) !important;  
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(12px) !important;  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i understood you clear:

your css is working but i guess you cant see any difference on screen.
cause you must give background img to behind object.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMTNS.jpg)

try this:

```
 body {
        background-image: url("https://www.lg.com/tr/images/TV/features/D04_TV-UHD-UM75-04-Quad-Core-Processor-Desktop.jpg");
    }
    .navbar
        {
            border:1px solid red;
    background-color: #ffffff10 !important;  
    
    backdrop-filter: blur(12px) !important;  
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(12px) !important;  
}
```

and some examples
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backdrop-filter/
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backdrop-filter/

if you cant override css class, you can use ID selector. Cause id is priority than class.

```
#navbar
    { color:red;}
```

if i understood you wrong, share a codepen link-or files please

Comment: I ended up using the ID selector, it works perfectly. Thanks!